# std::bind with template member function

Tags: templates, c++11, std-function, stdbind, function-binding

I have a strange problem that I cannot bind this template member function,
all this code compiles: http://ideone.com/wl5hS8

It's a simple code: I have a `ExecutionList` which should hold callable functions in a `std::vector`. I can now add functions by calling `ExecutionList::addFunctor`. But there, I cannot bind to `template<typename T> void Functor::calculate(T * t)`. I am asking me why, what is missing here, the compiler cannot somehow deduce what I have written in

```
m_calculationList.push_back( std::bind(&T::calculate<Type>, extForce, std::placeholders::_1 ) );
```

**Error: **

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
                 m_calculationList.push_back( std::bind(T::calculate<Type>, extForce, std::placeholders::_1 ) );
                                                                     ^
```

**The Code:**

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct MyType{
    static int a;
    int m_a;
    MyType(){a++; m_a = a;}

    void print(){
        std::cout << "MyType: " << a << std::endl;
    }
};
int MyType::a=0;


struct Functor{

    static int a;
    int m_a;

    Functor(){a++; m_a = a;}

    // Binding this function does not work 
    template<typename T>
    void calculate(T * t){}

    // Binding this function works!!!
    void calculate2(MyType * t){
        std::cout << " Functor: " << m_a <<std::endl;
        t->print();
    }

};

int Functor::a=0;

// Binding this function works!!!
template<typename T>
void foo( T * t){}

class ExecutionList{
    public:
        typedef MyType Type;

        template<typename T>
        void addFunctor(T * extForce){
            //m_calculationList.push_back( std::bind(&T::calculate<Type>, extForce, std::placeholders::_1 ) );   /// THIS DOES NOT WORK
            m_calculationList.push_back( std::bind(&T::calculate2, extForce, std::placeholders::_1 ) );
            m_calculationList.push_back( std::bind(&foo<Type>, std::placeholders::_1 ) );
        }


        void calculate(Type * t){
            for(auto it = m_calculationList.begin(); it != m_calculationList.end();it++){
                (*it)(t); // Apply calculation function!
            }
        }

    private:
        std::vector< std::function<void (Type *)> > m_calculationList;
};



int main(){
    MyType b;
    ExecutionList list;
    list.addFunctor(new Functor());
    list.addFunctor(new Functor());
    list.calculate(&b);
}
```

Comment: So that means I need some ``typename`` word? Does that make sense, since it is not a type but a function pointer

Comment: There's another disambiguator: `template`. `std::bind(&T::template calculate<Type>, ...)` should work. Also, *always* include the error message you get. "DOES NOT WORK" doesn't help.

Comment: ahhh damm it, I thought its one of these stupid things, but never used template infront of a type, only sometimes as in the case ``a.template foo<Type>`` if  ``foo`` is not deducable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the template keyword. If T is a template parameter and T::calculate refers to a template you need to tell the compiler that calculate is a template and not some static variable which you try to compare using the less-than operator with something else:

```
T::template calculate<Type>
```

I ran into the exact same problem a couple of years ago but today (post C++11) I would probably solve it with a lambda which is simpler:

```
std::function<void(Type*)> func = [obj](Type*param){obj.calculate(param);};
```

Anyhow, try to reduce the number of `new` uses. Look for a better way to manage your resources. Your code seems to leak a couple of functors.